# Irregular points for KKT theorem; $\min(x-4)^2+y^2$ for $x^2+y^2-9\le0,-x-3\le0,x-3\le0$ and $-y-2\le0$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am solving this optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\min (x-4)^2+y^2
\end{equation}
subject to

\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2-9\le0 \\
-x-3\le0\\
x-3\le0\\
-y-2\le0
\end{cases}
In the point (0,3) the first and the third constraints are active. However, their gradients are: $\nabla g_1=(6,0)$ and $\nabla g_2=(1,0)$ so they are not linearly independent hence KKT theorem cannot be applied. What should I do to qualify the point (3,0) has a minimum or a maximum?

Comment: For starters, you have only two variables, so the feasible domain and the isolines of the objective can be skethched.